# RedirectPermanent not redirecting to the url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm coding a simple URL shortener.

Everything is working, except the redirection.

Here is the code that tries to redirect:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Click(string segment)
    {
        string referer = Request.UrlReferrer != null ? Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() : string.Empty;
        Stat stat = await this._urlManager.Click(segment, referer, Request.UserHostAddress);
        return this.RedirectPermanent(stat.ShortUrl.LongUrl);
    }
```

When I input a link that is shortened, like this http://localhost:41343/5d8a2a, it redirects me to http://localhost:41343/www.google.com.br instead of www.google.com.br.

**EDIT**

After checking the answer, it works. Here is the final snippet of code.

```
if (!stat.ShortUrl.LongUrl.StartsWith("http://") && !stat.ShortUrl.LongUrl.StartsWith("https://"))
            return this.RedirectPermanent("http://" + stat.ShortUrl.LongUrl);
        else
            return this.RedirectPermanent(stat.ShortUrl.LongUrl);
```

Thanks!

Comment: And what does `LongUrl` return?

Comment: @DovydasSopa longUrl returns www.google.com

Comment: It works if the LongUrl contains http://. Is there a way aroud it, instead of checking if the url contains http://?

Comment: You need to make the `LongUrl` and absolute URL by including the protocol like `http://`. Otherwise it thinks you are trying to do a relative redirect.

Comment: @vcsjones is there a way around it? The only way I can find is to check if the url contains http://, if not, add it.

Comment: That's pretty much it. You can validate it as a full URL when adding, so people can't use something like "www.google.com" in the first place. Other than that, you'll just have to correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `RedirectPermanent()` try using `Redirect()` like below. The specified URL has to be a absolute URL else it will try to redirect to within your application.

You can check for existence of `http://` and add it accordingly

```
if(!stat.ShortUrl.LongUrl.Contains("http://"))
  return Redirect("http://" + stat.ShortUrl.LongUrl);
```

(OR)

Use `StartsWith()` string function

```
if(!stat.ShortUrl.LongUrl.StartsWith()("http://"))
  return Redirect("http://" + stat.ShortUrl.LongUrl);
```

Comment: Not `Contains`. Use `StartsWith`.